# Including %date% in creation of logfile is resulting in "path not found error"

Tags: windows-7, command-line, bash-scripting

I attempting to create dynamically-named log files based on today's date.
I'm using the examples found on the web, but none of them seem to be working for me.

```
C:\Users\Amit>echo hello > %date%.txt
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\Amit>echo hello > %date%.txt
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\Amit>echo hello > %date%.dat
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\Amit>echo hello > %date%.dat
The system cannot find the path specified.



C:\Users\Amit>echo hello > "%date%.dat"
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\Amit>echo hello > test.txt    #this works



C:\Users\Amit>echo hello >  %date%.txt
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\Amit>echo "testfile" >> backup-%DATE%.txt
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\Amit>echo "testfile" > backup-%DATE%.txt
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I'm copying and pasting a bunch of them as well.
I'm using **Windows 7**.

I can't figure out what mistake I'm making.

Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think %date% fetches the cute date?

Comment: Hmm Cute date? I'm sure she is :) @Ramhound

Comment: You need to set `date` first before you can use %date%. See my answer [Windows batch, Different regional setting, Rename directory YYYYmmDD\_HHmmSS](//superuser.com/a/1262349) for one way to get a locale independent date and time string.

Comment: @DavidPostill  I think I got it working now, by playing around with the date string and extracting part by part.

Comment: @DavidPostill: What do you mean by `set date`? How could the Windows date be not set?

Comment: @AxelKemper It is, but contains `/` characters, so cannot be used as the OP wants as part of a filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, you can get the date parts by extraction:

```
::  0123456789    offset table
::  12/01/2018    example of %DATE%, dependent on locale/country
set YYYY=%DATE:~6,4%
set DD=%DATE:~0,2%
set MM=%DATE:~3,2%

echo hello > %DD%_%MM%_%YYYY%.txt
```

The errors you got are caused by slashes in the `%DATE%` output.
These slashes are not tolerated within filenames.

Comment: @axeiKemper   Yes, after removing the slashes everything was working perfectly.